# UIButton setCenter crashing

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an array of buttons that I am creating. However, the code crashes at when I call setCenter.

```
buttonsArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        [buttonsArray addObject:[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]];
        UIButton *tempButton = [buttonsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [tempButton setFrameWidth:300.0 andHeight:50.0];
        [tempButton addBlackBorderWidth:1.0];
        [tempButton roundCornersBy:10.0];
        [tempButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [tempButton setColorToGradientFromColor:[UIColor grayColor] toColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [tempButton setButtonTextColorForNormalState:[UIColor whiteColor] highlightedState:[UIColor redColor]];
        [tempButton setCenter:CGPointMake([self screenUsableWidth] / 2.0, ([self screenUsableHeight] - 2.0 * MAIN_MENU_BUTTON_TO_SIDE_DISTANCE) * i / ([buttonsArray count] - 1) + MAIN_MENU_BUTTON_TO_SIDE_DISTANCE)]; //crash is here
    }
```

The error is `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [384 nan]'`

Comment: Read the error. One of the values is a NaN. If you can't figure out which one, store things in temporary variables until you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the `y` coordinate calculation is to divide by `([buttonsArray count] - 1)`.

The first time in the loop, this equates to 0. Dividing by 0 is generally considered a bad thing.

You need to change that calculation to avoid the division by zero. Perhaps changing that to your actual loop count instead of the current array count.

Comment: If that were the only zero, it would be `inf`, not `NaN`. `NaN` indicates that `i` is zero too.

Comment: @Kevin Good point. But the `i` being zero is fine once the part I mentioned is fixed.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't sure what a NaN was. Now I see my problem after moving around code. Thanks!

Comment: `NaN` is the mathematical value of "not a number".